# Highcharts Standalone Framework on Wordpress no longer working after updates

Tags: jquery, wordpress

Inserting this code into the header.php file used to work, but no longer does:

```
<script src="<?php echo esc_url( get_template_directory_uri() ); ?>/scripts/highcharts.js"></script>
```

Shortcodes show up on page, but not the charts. We have the highcharts.js file uploaded to the scripts folder. This used to work fine, but not after latest updates. Example: https://prepestuaries.org/testing/

Comment: Just now discovering that charts are visible except on Chrome browser!

Comment: Do you have any errors in the console?

Comment: Yes, it says "Mixed Content: The page at '<URL>' was loaded over HTTPS, but requested an insecure XMLHttpRequest endpoint '<URL>'. This request has been blocked; the content must be served over HTTPS." but I don't know how and where to fix this issue in the jQuery (?). The files are loaded and available via https but it's not retrieving them there...

Comment: And, the charts are not visible any more on any browser... they were yesterday, but not today!

Comment: You've used `highcharts` label, however, the problem seems to not be related to it. I suggest you ask this question with `wordpress` and `jquery` labels. Insert also the error message to it.